# How to install driver for ATI Rage 128 Pro Ultra TF?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, graphics

This is the driver in question, it promises to be the end of my graphics troubles with my old Rage 128 card.

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA5Mzk

The only trouble is, I'm not sure how to install the driver?

I'm running Ununtu 12.04.

Comment: Shouldn't Ubuntu recognize this card during installation?

Comment: The card is recognised, however playing whilst some videos the picture is stuttering, I thought with better drivers this may solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't a new or different driver than the one in Ubuntu already. It is a patch to support the newer acceleration architecture in Xorg, as the older one is slated to be removed. Getting this built would require a rebuild of the package it patches, by including the patch in the packaging.

It may possibly be slightly less buggy, than the current code is, but it is also a little slower, and unlikely to fix your video stuttering issues.

It does look like the patch was committed upstream though, in July 2012, so should be included in the `xserver-xorg-video-r128` package in Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.04. You may want to try a live image of one of those first, to see if the issues you're wanting to fix still occur there. If they don't, and a bug is not filed for your issues, it would be a good idea to report it, and it may be possible to get the fix released as an update to 12.04.

Comment: I've already tried installing 12.10 when I found the machine I'm working on.  It said that my card was not supported and I should use 12.04.  Where is the best place to file a bug report so I can see if I can get this added?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-r128/+filebug

Comment: Bug report filed.